# Android Apps' content sharing works perfectly on emulator, but crashes on real device

Tags: android

I'm a newbie to the android platform and I am developing an android app. Along with several features, there is a feature in the app and it is sharing contents like text, images etc. For initial testing I have used tablelayout, and inside this layout I have used rows and columns. More specifically there are only two columns. The first column contains some textual contents and the second column contains a button or label or text that represents "Share". And when any user taps the share option in the app, a popup will come out and user will get a list of goals (like Facebook, Twitter, Google+ etc.) where the user wants to share the content. So when I test this share option on the emulator it works fine, just perfect. But when I test the app on real device and taps the share option on real device, the app just crashes. I am not getting any idea why. Someone kindly suggest me the possible reasons for such problem. Thanks in advance. Below is my sample code I have used.

```
textContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
shareContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.share_content);
shareContent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textContent.getText());
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(
        Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share..."));
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include the Java stack trace for your crash, along with all of the code associated with that stack trace.

Comment: What version of Android is the emulator running compared to the phone, and what make/model is the phone?

Comment: #CommonsWare I have edited and added my sample code.

Comment: #Carl Poole, The emulator is using the latest version of android nougat, and the real device (Brand: Doogee) is using android lolipop.

Answer (score 0):

A list of respective applications will open if they are already installed in the device. If not, then system will fire an exception. Guard your method with try-catch block. And check which application are installed to match with your intent's action.